# Join 3 table with query builder in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have a 3 table questions,registrations,ssi_tracks i need to get details from the registraions table by corresponding to other two tables

i need to get details from registrations based on 
questions.question_schedul=0 ,ssi_tracks.track_first_status

i have wrote query but it says the column is not found here is my query

```
 $register = DB::table('registrations')
            ->join('questions', 'registrations.registration_id', '=', 'questions.question_id')
             ->join('ssi_tracks','registrations.registration_id','=','ssi_tracks.registration_id')
             ->select('address', 'model', 'chassis', 'delivery_date','ssi_tracks.track_first_status')
            ->where([["questions.question_schedul", "=", $dropselected] and ['ssi_tracks.track_first_status',0]])
             ->get();
```

Comment: what column name it says not found in query? please share name.

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'  @JinandraGupta

Comment: i need to filter by questions.question_schedul=0,ssi_tracks.track_first_status=0 like this  @JinandraGupta

Comment: I've answered. Please try and let me know if it is helpful for you. thanks

Comment: yea i will check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$register = DB::table('registrations as R')
             ->select('R.address', 'R.model', 'R.chassis', 'R.delivery_date','S.track_first_status')
             ->join('questions as Q', 'R.registration_id', '=', 'Q.question_id')
             ->join('ssi_tracks as S','R.registration_id','=','S.registration_id')
             ->where('Q.question_schedul', '=', $dropselected)
             ->where('S.track_first_status', '=', 0)
             ->get();
```

Make sure you have used the right column here from question table for matching registration id:

```
->join('questions as Q', 'R.registration_id', '=', 'Q.question_id')
```

Comment: It returns only 1 result, i have question_schedul=1 around 4 and track_first_status=0 around 3 but it only retruns only one @Jinandra Gupta

Comment: You want OR condition in where clause or AND? I mean this query extract the result for those record only who has question_schedul=1 and  track_first_status=0.

Comment: If you want either question_schedul=1 or track_first_status=0 it should extract result then try 

->where('Q.question_schedul', '=', $dropselected)
->orWhere('S.track_first_status', '=', 0)

Comment: i need the two status at a time not with i need AND condition @Jinandra Gupta  Like you said in the 2nd comment

Comment: Updated query in answered as you required. Please try.

Comment: Ok i will try that now

Comment: It seems your old query is working now,i don't know why it did'nt worked in the first palce,you can edit the answer  @Jinandra Gupta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169910/discussion-between-jinandra-gupta-and-abhijith).

Comment: Great!!. Please upvote if it is resolved ur problem. Thanks

Comment: change your answer                                                                                  
              ->where([['questions.question_schedul', '=', $dropselected]])
             ->where([['ssi_tracks.track_first_status', '=', 0]])                                                                         Not ->orWhere('S.track_first_status', '=', 0) Like you wrote before

Comment: change your answer                                                                                  
              ->where([['questions.question_schedul', '=', $dropselected]])
             ->where([['ssi_tracks.track_first_status', '=', 0]])                                                                         Not ->orWhere('S.track_first_status', '=', 0) Like you wrote before

Answer (score 0):

try this query :

```
$register = DB::table('registrations')
             ->leftJoin('questions', 'registrations.registration_id', '=', 'questions.question_id')
             ->leftJoin('ssi_tracks','registrations.registration_id','=','ssi_tracks.registration_id')
             ->select('registrations.address', 'registrations.model', 'registrations.chassis', 'registrations.delivery_date','ssi_tracks.track_first_status')
             ->where(['questions.question_schedul'=>$dropselected,'ssi_tracks.track_first_status'=>0])
             ->get();
```

Comment: It returns only 1 result, i have question_schedul=1 around 4 and track_first_status=0 around 3 but it only retruns only one @Saurabh Mistry

Comment: @Abhijith , make sure you are getting proper value in `$dropselected`

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dF1xdlVgCPvsR-2KBRQRoYczL3q5NIXb/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KxSeGrd6jIJMikLBd6zTEGeiYYV3xxYJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can check the link for table it own google drive @ Saurabh Mistry

Comment: @Abhijith , i find out why you are getting one 1 recored .....in photo given there are only 3 records in `ssi_tracks` where track_first_status=0  and suppose you choosen `registration id =3`  and for `registration id =3` there is only one record in question table with `question_id=3`.....so you are getting only one records

Comment: yes i should change to ssi_tracks.registration_id like this right